# How to hide a function based on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I have this class:

```
template <bool T1>
class Foo {
public:
    void doSomething() {}

    Foo<T1>& operator=(int a) {
        doSomething();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

But I want that the method `operator=` be hidden (by simply doing: `return *this`) if the template parameter `T1` is false.

I need that for instances of Foo, the lines:

```
Foo<false> foo;
foo = 20; //this should give a compilation error
```

So I tried specializing the class definition:

```
template<>
class Foo<false> {
private:
    Foo<false>& operator=(int a) {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

However, by doing this I lose the method `doSomething()` on instances that are `Foo<false>`, which is not what I need.

I've tried removing the `operator=` with boost::enable_if, like this:

```
typename boost::enable_if<
    boost::mpl::bool_<T1>
    , Foo<T1>
>::type&
operator=(int a) {
    callProxy();
    return *this;
}
```

But that makes me unable to have a class like the following:

```
class Bar {
public:
   Foo<true> assignable;
   Foo<false> unassignable;
};
```

I've also tried putting both methods in Foo and removing them with `boost::enable_if` and `boost::disable_if`, like this:

```
 template <bool T1>
 class Foo {
 public:
    void doSomething() {}

    typename boost::enable_if<
        boost::mpl::bool_<T1>
        , Foo<T1>
    >::type&
    operator=(int a) {
        doSomething();
        return *this;
    }

 private:
    typename boost::disable_if<
        boost::mpl::bool_<T1>
        , Foo<T1>
    >::type&
    operator=(int a) {
        return *this;
    }
 };
```

Which didn't work too (I expected that, but it was worth trying).

So, is it possible to get the behaviour I need, and if it is, how could I do it?

Comment: I'm confused why you need such behavior. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can statically assert the condition:

```
Foo<T1>& operator=(int a) {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(T1);
    doSomething();
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

why not just use a regular if()?

`if(T1) doSomething();`

Comment: That would work, but I need that for instances of Foo<false> calls for operator= give me a compilation error.

Comment: @Edison: So...then your code `class Bar { public: Foo<true> assignable; Foo<false> unassignable; };` **shouldn't** work.

Comment: Ok, then just add static int dummy[T1]; in the body of the operator=
When T1 is false, the array size will be zero, which is not allowed.  Or you could use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT.

Comment: Why not? I can provide a no-op operator=, like i did when specializing Foo with:
template <> class Foo<false> { private: Foo<false>& operator=(int a) { return *this; } };

Comment: @Edison: So, do you want a compile-error or a no-op operator? You must make up your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of special-casing the `false` case, you could special-case the `true` case, and only include the `operator=` in that case.

Comment: If I do that, the following code won't compile: class Bar { public: Foo<true> assignable; Foo<false> unassignable; };